# SOQL Query Nested Select

Tags: apex, soql

I wanted to do a nested select to save an extra Select statement. This is what I wrote but I dont think i have the syntax correct.

```
Select Name, 
( Select Id, Name, SBQQ__PriceBook__c From SBQQ__Quote__c Where Number = '901189')
from Pricebook2
```

Comment: Is there any relationship between `SBQQ__Quote__c` and `Pricebook2`. If yes, you can try `Select Name, 
( Select Id, Name, SBQQ__PriceBook__c From SBQQ__Quote__r Where Number = '901189')
from Pricebook2`. Appending `__r` instead of `__c`

Comment: Using `__r` is correct, but you must use the *relationship name*, not the sObject name. They're often different on custom relationships.

Comment: Yes there is a relationship. I changed it to __r but it errors and says "Didn't understand relationship 'SBQQ__Quote__r' in FROM part of query call."

Comment: This direction is often plural i.e. `SBQQ__Quotes__r`.

Comment: Please ***ask something*** when you post a `Question`.

Comment: ok. I thought I did do to the syntax being incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the custom object `SBQQ__Quote__c` > then fields & relationships, click on the lookup field to `Pricebook2` object > on this page under the section Lookup Options look for the **Child Relationship Name**. If it is `SBQQ__Quotes` then append the same with `__r`. So your query should look like this -

```
Select Name, 
( Select Id, Name, SBQQ__PriceBook__c From SBQQ__Quotes__r Where Number = '901189')
from Pricebook2
```